# can anyone tell me how to use javascript for selecting all items fetched from database into a checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is the code to fetch data from database and populate the checkbox:

```
<td>Applicable State</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" id="select2">Select All State</td>

<?php
$conn=get_dbconnect();
$sql="select name from states";
$rs = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);//odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($rs) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
        echo "<input type='checkbox' value='".$row['name']."' onclick='check(this)'; /> ".$row['name'];  
    }
}
mysqli_close($conn); [enter image description here][1]
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're Answer is here dude :

**HTML PART**

```
<form action="#">
<p><label><input type="checkbox" id="checkAll"/> Check all</label></p>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Loads of checkboxes</legend>
    <p><label><input type="checkbox" /> Option 1</label></p>
    <p><label><input type="checkbox" /> Option 2</label></p>
    <p><label><input type="checkbox" /> Option 3</label></p>
    <p><label><input type="checkbox" /> Option 4</label></p>
</fieldset>
```

**Jquery Part**

```
$("#checkAll").change(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

**Important** Don't forget to include jquery CDN in header tags

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: thanks dude, but i want code in pure javascript